# How to create directories automatically in linux?

Tags: linux, mkdir

I am having a file named **temp.txt** where inside this file it contains the following content
https://abcdef/12345-xyz

https://ghifdfg/5426525-abc

I need to create a directories automatically in linux by using only th number part from each line in the file.
So the output should be something like **12345** and  **5426525** directories created.

Any approach on how to do this could be helpful.

This is the code that i searched and got from internet,wherein this code, new directories will be created by the file name that starts with BR and W0 .

```
for file in {BR,W0}*.*; do
dir=${file%%.*}
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to adapt that code to your needs? Have you put in the effort to learn shell scripting?

Comment: Did you read [mkdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) & [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) *carefully* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each URL is of the form

```
http[s]://any/symbols/some_digits-some_letters
```

Then you indeed could use the simple prefix and suffix modifiers in shell variable expansion.

`${x##*/}` expands to the suffix part of `x` that  starts after the last slash `/`.

`${y%%-*}` expands to the prefix part of `y` before the first `-`.

```
while read x ; do
  y=${x##*/} 
  z=${y%%-*} 
  mkdir $z
done < temp.txt
```